# Create a new column for a given range of numbers with same frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I haven't been able to find the exact solution to my problem.
My data set has a column called 'Priority' which contains string values.

```
Priority  
low        
low       
low        
low        
low        
medium    
medium     
medium     
medium     
medium    
high       
high       
high       
high
```

I want to add column "Num" that will give each 'Priority' number based on a range of numbers (which would be 0 to 3). As a result, each 'Priority' would have a number between 1 to 3 with the same frequency.

For example :

```
Priority Num 
low        1
low        2
low        3
low        1
low        2
low        3
medium     1
medium     2
medium     3
medium     1
medium     2
high       1
high       2
high       3
high       1
```

After many other attempts, this is my best solution for now but it's return duplicates in range (1,3)

```
x = pd.DataFrame(
    [[l, n] for l in data. Priority for n in range(1,6)],
    columns=['Priority', 'Num'])
```

Do you have another idea?

Comment: df['num']=df.groupby('Priority').cumcount()%3+1

Comment: What do you mean "with the same frequency"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function
assume `df` is the name of your data set

```
df['num'] = df.Priority.apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='low' else(2 if x=='medium' else 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

to read your data I use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) together [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv)

```
data = '''Priority\n  
          low\n        
          low\n      
          low\n        
          low\n        
          low\n        
          medium\n    
          medium\n     
          medium\n     
          medium\n     
          medium\n    
          high\n       
          high\n       
          high\n       
          high\n'''
```

to call `groupby` in `'Priority'` column to invoke `cumcount()` method as is explained by [@Raymond Kwok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11065465/raymond-kwok)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# read data
df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0)

# use groupby to store value as accumulate count
df['num']=df.groupby('Priority').cumcount()%3+1
```

output:

```
>>> df
   Priority  num
0       low    1
1       low    2
2       low    3
3       low    1
4       low    2
5    medium    1
6    medium    2
7    medium    3
8    medium    1
9    medium    2
10     high    1
11     high    2
12     high    3
13     high    1
```